# Why isn't ensureIndex() working as I would expect?

Tags: mongodb

Given the code

```
express = require('express')
bodyParser = require('body-parser')
url = require('url')

app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.set 'port', process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use express.static(__dirname + '/public')

mongodb = require('mongodb')
mongojs = require('mongojs')
dbLocation = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/wesave-companion'; 
db = mongojs(dbLocation)
transactions = db.collection 'transactions'
transactions.ensureIndex({item_id: 1}, unique: true)

app.post '/transactions', (req, resp) ->
  transaction = buildTransaction req.query
  createTransaction transaction
  resp.status = 200
  resp.send 'ok'

createTransaction = (transaction, user) ->
  transactions.insert transaction, (err, doc) ->
    return err if err
    return doc if doc
```

I would generally expect that based on mongodb documentation, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/ my db would not be allowing multiple records with an identical 'item_id' key to exist, but that is not the case.

I've tried writing the `ensureIndex` method as both:

```
transactions.ensureIndex({item_id: 1}, {unique: true})
```

and

```
transactions.ensureIndex({"item_id": 1}, {unique: true})
```

and

```
transactions.ensureIndex({'item_id': 1}, {unique: true})
```

But clearly, using the mongoshell, records entries are definitely duplicating.  What am I missing here?

[image: https://cl.ly/image/0X0m0R2U3s3T/Image%202014-11-19%20at%2011.24.47%20AM.png]

Interestingly, if I attempt to write the index directly to the db, I get the below response, which I'm not sure how to interpret.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/2j1x2Z1D3a30/Image%202014-11-19%20at%2011.26.20%20AM.png]

What direction should I be digging?  Thx.

Comment: Did you reset your mongodb? and use {unique : true, dropDups : true} instead

Comment: `db.transactions.count()` and `db.transactions.count({item_id: "5469..."})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any duplicates. You're calling `db.transactions.find()`, which returns the entire contents of your collection.

It returns one document, which means your collection contains exactly one document.

You're calling it three times, which, you will note, returns the same thing every time.

Comment: Right, thats a bit of brainsnafu on my part, thanks for pointing that out.